# Get virtualenv or python path in views

Tags: django, python-3.x, subprocess, virtualenv

I'm running a Django project with an virtualenv, I want to get in views the path of running python or of the virtual environment that I'm using

The goal is to pass this path to subprocess to execute a script

Thank you

Comment: i think this is redundant, subprocess to execute a script will auto use the same python venv as django does.

Comment: Also, if you want to run a Python script in the same environment, why don't you import it rather than running as a subprocess?

Comment: @Ykh indeed but only in my local machine, when I switch on prod it select the first python (2.7) version installed and no virtualenv

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm using subprocess because I'm in views file and I want to pass some parameters and track the stdout
my script is a django-admin commands

Comment: Then you should use `management.call_command`, see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code). Even better, refactor your code so that both management command and view call a common function.

Comment: Thank you @DanielRoseman it works fine with management.call_command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of @DanielRoseman was great, I used management.call_command instead of subprocess and it works fine, the correct virtual environement is passed implicitly

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `request.META`?

I found out some useful information there.
(I'm using `pyenv` now and I found `PATH`, `PYENV_DIR`, `PYENV_ROOT`, `PYENV_VIRTUAL_ENV`, `VIRTUAL_ENV` and so on.)

Comment: Already tried it but these variables only are given when I'm in dev env